# Pandas groupby 2 columns, select max of 3rd column

Tags: pandas

Edit: requested to update this post with existing code.  I'm using arcpy to convert a Feature Class to a numpy array and then to pandas dataframe:

```
itsct_nparr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(prItsct, ['FID_preproc','PLANREG_NAME','Shape_Area'])
#create a pandas DataFrame objects from the NumPy arrays
itsct_df = DataFrame(itsct_nparr, columns=['FID_preproc','PLANREG_NAME','Shape_Area'])
maxarea = itsct_df.groupby(['FID_preproc','PLANREG_NAME'], as_index=False).max()
maxarea.to_csv(csvout)
del itsct_nparr
```

As title suggests, I'm attempting to group by FID_preproc and NAME using the max of Shape_Area.

```
Input:   
FID_preproc NAME Shape_Area 
1340         A   25952.35775 
1341         A   118099.5219 
1341         B   305220.1244 
1342         A   12053.13585 


Desired Result:   
FID_preproc NAME Shape_Area 
1340         A   25952.35775 
1341         B   305220.1244 
1342         A   12053.13585
```

This gets me close to what I want but produces the same result as first sample set above.

```
maxarea = itsct_df.groupby(['FID_preproc','PLANREG_NAME'], as_index=False).Shape_Area.max()
```

Comment: what is your question? the code you have written willl give you your result,

Comment: When I save the maxarea datafram to a csv it generates the same as the "Input" sample above, not the "desired result".

Comment: does `maxarea = itsct_df.loc[itsct_df.groupby('FID_preproc', as_index=False)['Shape_Area'].idxmax()]` work then?

Comment: it doesn't like the .loc?  "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'loc'"

Comment: is `DataFrame` a pandas DataFrame or some other kind of DataFrame? What does `type(itsct_df)` display?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>  It must be version of Pandas installed then?

Comment: what is your version of pandas? You must be running a really old version, try upgrading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you actually just want the max shape area for each FID_preproc:

```
In[34]:
maxarea = df.loc[df.groupby('FID_preproc', as_index=False)['Shape_Area'].idxmax()]
maxarea

Out[34]: 
   FID_preproc NAME    Shape_Area
0         1340    A   25952.35775
2         1341    B  305220.12440
3         1342    A   12053.13585
```

If you `groupby` on the first column and then call `idxmax` this will return the index labels of the max values, you can then pass these to the orig df to index

Comment: Ed, I get the error "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'loc'"

Comment: Please post raw data and code that produces this error

Comment: Ed -- that sample data is what's actually in the source (could be a csv for example) that populates the dataframe.  I copied and pasted your example solution and it generated that error.

Comment: I ask again, post raw data, code that loads this data into your df, the code you tried that produced this error. Telling me the error without this is counter-productive

Comment: @user2309282 please try my code! and tell your output.

Comment: @kanavanand your code just reproduces the orig df, think about it you group on the first two columns so it looks for unique combinations of the 2, you then call max, this will return 2 rows for FID_preproc1341 which in effect returns the orig df

Comment: The OP is after 3 rows, which is what my code produces and is what the OP's desired result is

Comment: I'm now on a machine that has current version of pandas and tried your example but it generates the same as the Input sample I posted in the OP. maxarea = itsct_df.loc[itsct_df.groupby('FID_preproc', as_index=False)['Shape_Area'].idxmax()]

Comment: Then you have some other issue as your posted sample works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
maxarea = itsct_df.groupby(['FID_preproc','PLANREG_NAME'], as_index=False).max()
```

Comment: Thank you Kanav.  However, this produces the same as the Input example, not the Desired Result.